# Type parameter to variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

how to getValue of property class with this method?

```
public static int SQLInsert<TEntity>(TEntity obj) where TEntity : class
{
    foreach (var item in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        //item.GetValue(?,null);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item.GetValue(obj, null);
```

that would work

Answer (score 5):

`item` will be a `PropertyInfo`. You'd use:

```
object value = item.GetValue(obj, null);
```

Note that you're pretty much ignoring the `TEntity` type parameter at the moment. You may want to use:

```
foreach (var property in typeof(TEntity).GetProperties())
```

That way if someone calls

```
SQLInsert<Customer>(customer)
```

and the value of `customer` *actually* refers to a subclass of `Customer` with extra properties, only the properties of `Customer` will be used.

Comment: +1 Very good point about TEntity Jon, those kinds of subtleties are easily missed.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, instead of indexer you can use null value:

```
public static int SQLInsert<TEntity>(TEntity obj) where TEntity : class
{
    var indexer = new object[0];
    foreach (var item in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        item.GetValue(obj,indexer);
    }
    return 1;
}
```